# How can I add Support module's tickets to the homepage?

Tags: nodes

I am trying out the [Support](http://drupal.org/project/support) module to create a client support ticketing system. Out of the box it seems to be configured so that I need to navigate to mysite.com/support to view the table of support tickets. How can I change this so that the support tickets appear on the homepage? Drupal version is 7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the default front page for your site in the admin section at example.com/admin/config/system/site-information.  Enter `support` and it will now be your front page.

[image: Default Front Page]